# device.platform is giving "device is not defined" phonegap

Tags: android, xml, cordova

Cordova version : 3.5.0

I am trying to implement push notification using [pushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin). But when I run this application on android platform(I haven't tried other platforms), There is a error "device is not defined".

I searched for this error and came across these questions [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199051/device-is-not-defined-error-pops-up-when-launching-my-phonegap-push-notification) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435336/cant-get-phonegap-device-platform-to-work)
solution of link1 doesn't work for me.

About link2's solution, I am pasting my /android/res/xml/config.xml here:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.aubergine.resqv1" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop" />
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="PushPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.plugin.gcm.PushPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <name>resQ</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

so if anyone can help it would be great.

here is my javascript(.js) code:

```
var pushNotification;
            

function onDeviceReady() {
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e)
    {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>backbutton event received</li>');
        
        if( $("#home").length > 0)
        {
            // call this to get a new token each time. don't call it to reuse existing token.
            //pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
            e.preventDefault();
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
        else
        {
            navigator.app.backHistory();
        }
    }, false);

    try 
    { 
        pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
  $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering ' + device.platform + '</li>');
        if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' ||
                device.platform == 'amazon-fireos' ) {
pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"788549744842","ecb":"onNotification"});        // required!
        } else {
            pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});    // required!
        }
    }
    catch(err) 
    { 
        txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n"; 
        txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n"; 
        $("#app-status-ul").append(txt); 
    } 
}

// handle APNS notifications for iOS
function onNotificationAPN(e) {
    if (e.alert) {
         $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>push-notification: ' + e.alert + '</li>');
         // showing an alert also requires the org.apache.cordova.dialogs plugin
         navigator.notification.$("#app-status-ul").append(e.alert);
    }
        
    if (e.sound) {
        // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
        var snd = new Media(e.sound);
        snd.play();
    }
    
    if (e.badge) {
        pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
    }
}

// handle GCM notifications for Android
function onNotification(e) {
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');
    
    switch( e.event )
    {
        case 'registered':
        if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
        {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
            // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
            // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
            console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
            $("#app-status-ul").append(e.regid);
        }
        break;
        
        case 'message':
            // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
            // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
            if (e.foreground)
            {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                  
                    // on Android soundname is outside the payload. 
                        // On Amazon FireOS all custom attributes are contained within payload
                        var soundfile = e.soundname || e.payload.sound;
                        // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                        // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
                        var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+ soundfile);

                my_media.play();
            }
            else
            {   // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                if (e.coldstart)
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                else
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
            }
                
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
            //android only
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
            //amazon-fireos only
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> TIMESTAMP: ' + e.payload.timeStamp + '</li>');
        break;
        
        case 'error':
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
        break;
        
        default:
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
        break;
    }
}

function tokenHandler (result) {
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
    // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
    // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
}

function successHandler (result) {
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
}

function errorHandler (error) {
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```

Comment: Remove the plugin and try again

Comment: The problem is probably in your javascript. You are trying to use a var named device, which is undefined. post your js code for more.

Comment: hey @shammon, I have tried reinstalling/readding plugin but it is not working.. :(

Comment: hi @mentat, I have edited my question with js code

Comment: Check you get reg id correctly

Comment: @shammon, reg id is correct. error is "device is not defined"

Answer (score 4):

- cordova -v
- cordova create Test
- cd Test
- cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
- cordova platform add [ios|android|wp8]
- cordova build

Comment: Hey Tony, I did that only with cordova commands :) and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
....
```